# Issue with floating divs - how can I have the widgets alongside the posts, not below?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, css-float

I am struggling to figure out how to align widgets to the right of the main column on this page: http://carolineelisa.com/wordpress/

It seems that the top 3 widgets are forcing the content area to the full width, so that the right hand side widgets drop below the left column.

Any tips for achieving this with CSS? I'd rather not have to mess with the templates of functions.php file to move the top widgets into their own div.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems CSS will not suffice in this case...

Thanks @Frost and @Justin Lucas for your suggestions. For my exact needs it seems that I need to move the top 3 widgets out of the #content div and place them above.

So now the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="feature" class="widget widget_text widget-widget_text">
<div id="feature" class="widget widget_text widget-widget_text">
<div id="feature" class="widget widget_text widget-widget_text">
<div id="content" class="hfeed content">
<div id="primary" class="sidebar aside">
```

For anyone who may be interested, I did this by creating a new sidebar element in my child theme (of Hybrid) by adding the following to the functions.php file:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Features',
    'id' => 'id-of-widget-area',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="feature" class="widget %2$s widget-%2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>'
) );
add_action( 'hybrid_before_container', 'my_widget_area', 20 ); 

function my_widget_area() {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'id-of-widget-area' );
}
```

I got this from: http://themehybrid.com/support/topic/new-widget-area#post-17991

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the two right side divs before the post divs.

```
<div id="content" class="hfeed content">
<div id="primary" class="sidebar aside">
```

This instead

```
<div id="primary" class="sidebar aside">
<div id="content" class="hfeed content">
```

Comment: +1 - yup, that fixed it for me. Nice work Frost! Can you explain why it worked though? I don't see why.

Comment: I must say I don't know the exact explanation, but it is always good to place `float:right;` before `float:left` if you want them side by side (if it doesn't work the other way around) ;)

Comment: Thanks Frost. This would involve changing the Wordpress template or functions.php file - guess I will have to do so!

Comment: You should be able to fix it with some `position:absolute;` of the `<div id="primary" class="sidebar aside">` but I would suggest the swop instead

Comment: Thanks again Frost! Yes, absolute positioning would work, but then cause a problem on the other pages that do not have the top 3 widgets. So I guess I am going to try and edit the functions.php file now...

Comment: P.s. Your answer above (the swap) didn't quite work for me, as then the 3 top widgets no longer run across the top, but rather are on two lines in the left column.  I think i will have to move the top 3 widgets out of the "content" div. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your  inside

```
<div id="content" class="hfeed content">    
<div id="utility-before-content" class="sidebar utility">
<div id="primary"></div>
<div id="post-49" class="hentry post publish post-1 odd author-admin sticky category-news">
...
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. This would involve changing the Wordpress template or functions.php file - guess I will have to do so!

Comment: P.s. For your response to work, the "utility-before-content" div holding the 3 top widgets needs to be above the "content" div. Also the posts need to remain inside the "content" div. Cheers.